# Remove OS from Multirom & install ubuntu touch properly

Tags: nexus-7, twrp, multirom-manager

I have Nexus 7 2012 model. I have installed MultiRom Manager & tried to install Ubuntu Touch Saucy. I tried twice & both failed. As a result now I have 3 options at boot including two Ubuntu, none of which works.

The error I face in running

```
Path /realdata//media/0/multirom/roms/ubuntu_sauc1/data.img not found
Failed to find boot file: /realdata/media/0/multirom/roms/ubuntu_sauc1
```

I guess the problem lies with the fact that, TWRP stops in the middle of some finishing work, when I reboot from android just after installation through manager & as I press power button it starts with MultiRom choices. TWRP crashes as soon as any button is touched. That's probably the reason its failing.

I assume its a lot of questions at a time, but any sort of help is highly appreciated.